# Why does IE screw up my icon hover?

Tags: html, css

Look at [my blog](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com) in Chrome and then look at it in IE. IE drags all the icons up, which was what I was trying to get rid of in the first place with a previous question. Any ideas on how to make it the same?

Comment: Have you used "position:fixed"? It is not well supported in ie.

Comment: Which IE are you talking about?

Comment: IE 8, and I can't use a position on the icons because for whatever reason it messes with ToolTip (Which is the post that pops up)

Comment: I'm not sure whether it will solve the problem, but there are some javascript errors on your page. Perhaps it's a good idea to get rid of those first and see how it looks. IE has a tendency to render things differently when Javascript errors appear. Also what you try to achieve with the icons moving up on hover, I think is possible in pure CSS, perhaps you can remove the whole JS and make it a lot more lightweight?

Comment: O well I don't know what errors your getting, but the entire page is done 100% in CSS and HTML. Absolutely no JS on the page. I will see what the error is, because usually Tumblr always gets um this pop up blocker script so ill check it out, thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

You are loading jquery so there may be something combined with external loading scripts that cause the IE error. It runs incredibly slow in IE for me, and obviously doesn't look right.

I would recommend you start out by using a reset style to make sure all margins, etc. are zeroed out.

[Meyer's reset styles](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

(these should go in the top of your css before any other styles are defined)